# Using GNU parallel command with aprun command?

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel, cray

I am trying to run this on *Cray XE6*:

```
aprun -n 1 sh -c 'parallel -j8 :::: s.txt'
```

where in *s.txt* I have 16 lines like this:

```
python hello.py > 01.out
```

`hello.py` just prints *hello*. My script runs forever. And I am running it on one compute node which has 32 cores. Plan was to submit first 8 `hello.py` on it to run in `parallel` and when they finish to go for another 8. I am new to `parallel` command, can someone please see if there is something wrong with my syntax, in particular how to use it with [`aprun`](http://docs.cray.com/cgi-bin/craydoc.cgi?mode=Show;q=;f=man/alpsm/10/cat1/aprun.1.html) command.

Comment: The parallel part looks fine. The python part is a bit surprising: Are you sure it is '/hello.py' and not './hello.py'?

Comment: yes, it's just type. I switched from python 2.7.3 to 2.7.10 and it works